# Grails paginate database results on same transaction?

Tags: hibernate, spring, grails, grails-orm

I'd like to be able to paginate my database results with something like the `CriteriaBuilder`, but I need my results to be consistent as to a single point in time.

Is there an easy  way to somehow paginate and keep the select within the same transaction/

Comment: Obviously you could do this by storing all the results in a cache (e.g. session), but that would defeat one of main benefits of pagination, i.e. only retrieving the records you need. Good question, looking forward to some more useful answers than this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you discarded to store the whole result set in memory using `ScrollableResult`?

Look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html)

`DomainObject.createCriteria().scroll{}` returns a ScrollableResult

Comment: How do I use this within grails? This is what I need, but I'd like to specify the grouping size of the results.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with grails. In hibernate you can move or just iterate over the collection.

Comment: The Grails documentation contains information on how to get a scrollable ResultSet from a Criteria query: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html

Answer (score -2):

Specify the offset you want in the criteria, based in the current page number.

```
def results = DomainClass.withCriteria {
   firstResult ( (currentPageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage)
   maxResults (itemsPerPage)
}
```

To know the total number of pages, you'll need another query:

```
def numberOfPages = DomainClass.count()
if(numberOfPages != 0) numberOfPages = numberOfPages / itemsPerPage + 1
```

Comment: Does this all happen in the same transaction?

Comment: Yes, it does not load rows that are outside the specified range.

Comment: I'm not quite sure you understand what I mean. If a row 11 is updated while I retrieve rows 1-10, I don't want the update.

Comment: If you don't want to load all the results at one time, there's no way to do that. Is it important to save memory? If it's not, you can simply list all the results and store them in the session object (session.setAttribute "results", DomainClass.list()). Then read from the session instead of from the database, and you'll not see further changes. Problems come when the result set is large.

Comment: Nope, you're wrong. Looks like `ScrollableResult` does just what I need it to, on databases that support it.

Comment: Ok, but without caching all the results? Doesn't it load everything up first? If it does that someway, then I'm really impressed. But anyway, "How long you live, so long you learn" :)